# input value is not picking any style & margin under paper-input-container

Tags: css-selectors, polymer, polymer-1.0, paper-elements, polymer-3.x

input value is not getting aligned in  under paper-input-container. while debugging it is displaying under #shadow-root inside

```
     <iron-input slot="input"> 
           <slot id="content"> <input> </slot>
     </iron-input>
```

I tried adding text-align attribute under paper-input. like

```
     --paper-input-container-input:{
         text-align:center;
         margin-right : -30px;
     }
```

The code for search-box is like

```
     <oe-input label = "search" value = "{{text}}"></oe-input>
```

It is aligning it to center, but margin-right is not working.
I tried styling input directly like

```
     input{ all: inherit }
```

Answer (score 0):

has to modify --paper-input-container-input-focus